# What is the purpose of these instructions before the main preamble?

Tags: disassembly, x86, gcc

I wrote a small C program below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int sub(int x, int y){
  return 2*x+y;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int a;
  a = atoi(argv[1]);
  return sub(argc,a);
}
```

Compiled with gcc 5.4.0 and target 32 bit x86. I got the following in disassembly:

```
0804841b <main>:
 804841b: 8d 4c 24 04           lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 804841f: 83 e4 f0              and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048422: ff 71 fc              pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 8048425: 55                    push   %ebp
 8048426: 89 e5                 mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048428: 53                    push   %ebx
 8048429: 51                    push   %ecx
 804842a: 83 ec 10              sub    $0x10,%esp
 804842d: 89 cb                 mov    %ecx,%ebx
....
```

What are the first three instructions before `push %ebp` doing? I haven't seen those in older gcc compiled binaries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### What the Instructions Are Doing

> What are the first three instructions before `push %ebp` doing?

Namely,

```
 804841b: 8d 4c 24 04           lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx      <-  1
 804841f: 83 e4 f0              and    $0xfffffff0,%esp    <-  2
 8048422: ff 71 fc              pushl  -0x4(%ecx)          <-  3
```

This is easy to see if `gdb` (or some other debugger) is used to step through the code.

1. > `804841b: 8d 4c 24 04           lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx`

At this point in the process, the memory address in register `$esp` is `0xffffd13c`, so `4(%esp)` = `$esp+4` = `0xffffd140`:

```
>>> x/x $esp+4
0xffffd140: 0x01
```

This means that the `lea` instruction loads the effective address of `0x4(%esp)`, `0xffffd140`, into `$ecx`.

---

2. > `804841f: 83 e4 f0              and    $0xfffffff0,%esp`

Next, the value in `$esp`, `0xffffd13c`, is ANDed with `0xfffffff0`:

```
0xffffd13c:            11111111111111111101000100111100
0xfffffff0:       AND  11111111111111111111111111110000
                  -------------------------------------
                       11111111111111111101000100110000
```

This results in the value `0xffffd130`, which is stored in `$esp`. This is equivalent to

`0xffffd13c` - `0x0c` = `0xffffd130`.

This has the effect of creating 12 bytes of space on the process runtime stack. On a side note, the value -16 would be represented as `0xfffffff0`, so we could think of

`and $0xfffffff0,%esp`

as

`and $-16,%esp`

This is done to [keep the stack aligned to a 16-byte boundary](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/basic-reversing-question-about-local-variable/14883#14883), since the next instruction (see 3) decrements the stack pointer by 4 and then saves a value to the stack.

---

3. > `8048422: ff 71 fc              pushl  -0x4(%ecx)`

As a result of `lea 0x4(%esp),%ecx` from earlier, the value in `$ecx` is equivalent to what had been `$esp+4` (that is, `0xffffd140`). As a result,

`-0x4(%ecx)` = `0xffffd140` - 4 = `0xffffd13c`.

This was the value of `$esp` at the beginning of `main()`. This value is now saved on the process runtime stack via a `pushl` instruction.

---

**summary:**

```
 lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx         // load 0xffffd140 into $ecx
 and    $0xfffffff0,%esp       // subtract 0x0c (decimal 12) from $esp
 pushl  -0x4(%ecx)             // decrement $esp by 4, save 0xffffd13c on stack
```

---

### The Purpose of these Instructions

> What is the purpose of these instructions before the main preamble?

A clue about the purpose of these instructions is the fact that they are executed prior to the conventional function prologue:

```
8048425: 55                    push   %ebp
8048426: 89 e5                 mov    %esp,%ebp
```

According to the [System V Application Binary Interface Intel386 Architecture Processor Supplment, Fourth Edition](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/elf/abi386-4.pdf), after the execution of the function prologue `$ebp+4` is the location on the runtime stack of the return address.

[image: SYS V ABI i386 supplement C stack frame]

The address saved on the stack at `$ebp+4` by the instruction

`8048422: ff 71 fc              pushl  -0x4(%ecx)`

is `0xffffd13c`. This is a pointer to `0xf7e12637`, the address of offset 247 in `__libc_start_main()`:

```
>>> x/x $ecx-4
0xffffd13c: 0xf7e12637
>>> x/x 0xf7e12637
0xf7e12637 <__libc_start_main+247>: 0x8310c483
```

This indicates that the return address of `main()` is in function `__libc_start_main()`.

As for `$ecx`, this register simply holds the value of `argc`:

```
>>> x/x $ecx
0xffffd140: 0x00000001
```

Note that since variable `a` is never used, the compiler optimizes out the call to `atoi`.

So to answer the question directly, the instructions in `main()` prior to the prologue pass an argument to `main()` (the value of `argc`) and save the return address of `main()` on the runtime stack.

### The C Runtime Environment and Linux Process Anatomy

Naturally, the next question is "What is `__libc_start_main`?" According to [Linux Standard Base PDA Specification 3.0RC1](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/baselib---libc-start-main-.html):

> The `__libc_start_main()` function shall initialize the process, call the main function with appropriate arguments, and handle the return from `main()`.

So where does `__libc_start_main()` come from? The short answer is that it is a function in the shared object `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so` which is dynamically linked into the executable ELF binary:

```
 $ ldd [binary_name]
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7764000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7586000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56640000)
```

In addition to `__libc_start_main()`, the function `__gmon_start__`, also part of process initialization, is dynamically linked to the executable ELF binary as well:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms [binary_name]

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4 (2)
     2: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     3: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.0 (3)
     4: 0804851c     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 _IO_stdin_used
```

Here is the complete picture, from [**Linux x86 Program Start Up or - How the heck do we get to main()?**](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) by Patrick Horgan:

[image: C process initialization call graph]

On a final note, if the return address of `main()` of `0xf7e12637` is examined more closely, we see that this address lies outside of the `text` segment as well as the runtime stack. This address, located in `__libc_start_main()`, is actually located in the memory-mapped segment in virtual memory, as shown by this diagram from Gustavo Duarte's article [**Anatomy of a Program in Memory**](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/):

[image: Linux Process Layout in VM]

Answer (score 7):

## What does this do?

These three statements serve to *move* the stackframe of `main`, beginning with its return address, to the next 16-byte-aligned address.

```
lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx    # save address of arguments
and    $0xfffffff0,%esp  # align stack
pushl  -0x4(%ecx)        # move return address
...                      # continue normal preamble
```

At the same time, the arguments to `main` (`argc` and `argv`) are not moved, so a pointer to them is saved in `%ecx`.

Recall the layout of the stack upon entering `main`:

```
%esp+8:  argv (a pointer to an array of pointers)
%esp+4:  argc (a 32-bit integer)
%esp+0:  return address (from call)
```

The arguments sit right above the return address, so `%esp+4` is saved to `%ecx` before the stack pointer is adjusted.
Next, `%ecx` also serves as our pointer to locate the original return address, `-4(%ecx)`, which we push to our new stack frame.

After the rest of the preamble, the stack will look like this:

```
%ecx+4:  argv pointer
%ecx+0:  argc
%ecx-4:  original return address
         ...
%esp+4:  copy of return address
%esp+0:  saved base pointer
```

In your code, you can also see that `%ecx` is pushed onto the stack (i.e. saved as a local variable) after the preamble; it will be restored from there at the end of the function which will look like this:

```
...
mov    -0x8(%ebp),%ecx   # load pointer to argc
leave                    # unwind stack frame, pop %ebp
lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp   # restore original stack pointer
ret                      # jump out, using the original return address!
```

## Why is all this done at all?

Modern processors like data aligned to 16-byte boundaries for various reasons; some operations may take significant performance hits otherwise, others might not work at all.

Adjusting the `main` stack frame once allows the rest of the code to run without further adjustment as long as care is taken to always allocate stack in multiples of 16 bytes before a call. That is why you will often see something like this:

```
sub    $0xc,%esp    # pad stack by 12 bytes
push   %eax         # push 4-byte argument
call   puts
```

**NB:** The x86-64 ABI makes the 16-byte stack alignment mandatory. Incidentally this means that you *will not* find a frame adjustment on `main` in 64-bit code - the stack is already aligned.

Comment: Welcome! Based on what you have written so far, I look forward to reading your future posts.

Comment: Thanks! I came here to look this up and afterwards felt that, while your answer is quite elaborate, it was missing a few details. Since as a new user I couldn't comment, I took a shot at my own. Hope you don't mind! :)

Comment: I like this better than @SYS_V's answer (no offense to SYS_V). I don't believe SYS_V's answer address "what is the purpose". It does a great job of explaining what the instructions do. The answer seems to be very very simple. Above and beyond the obvious alignment-optimization "At the same time, the arguments to main (argc and argv) are not moved, so a pointer to them is saved in %ecx." Beautiful. Thanks a ton.