# radare2 shows main function arguments argv as pointer to char on the stack, not as pointer to pointer to char

Tags: debugging, radare2, gdb, stack, entry-point

Well, I've been digging around *process command line arguments* as well as *environment variables* a bit these last days, especially looking up the way `main` function arguments were pushed onto the stack.

So far I've got it that a certain `_libc_start_main()` function is responsible of setting up everything the `main()` function needs in terms of parameters before actually calling it.
Without getting into much [details](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/15175/24851), I've noticed that when debugging a simple `main` program, the `main` stack frame is different whether we look it up in `radare2` or `gdb`.
For instance, let's take this minimalist C program :

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
}
```

And simply debug it without any additional parameters :

### With GDB

After setting a breakpoint on the first assembly instruction of `main` (I couldn't dump the stack frame without running the program),
what I got in `gdb` is something very sensible, as one can see :

```
(gdb) x/3xw $esp
0xffffcfbc:     0xf7db7b41          0x00000001      0xffffd054      
#                  ^                    ^               ^     
#              PC (somewhere          argc            argv             
#          in __libc_start_main())
```

Now by actually inspecting the pointed out memory regions for `argv` :

```
(gdb) x/2xw 0xffffd054   # argv
0xffffd054:     0xffffd1ef      0x00000000
#                  ^                ^ 
#                argv[0]          argv[argc]
#           (another pointer)              

(gdb) x/s 0xffffd1ef  # argv[0]
0xffffd1ef:     "<path>/argvonstack32"
#                      ^ 
#                  Exepected program name
```

So what was basically pushed onto the `main` stack frame, for both `argv` and `envp` (even if I didn't show the dump for `envp` for simplicity's sake) is exactly what we were entitled to expect from a debugger, that is a *pointer to pointer to `char`* (as stated in the `main` function signature).

### With Radare2

Without setting any breakpoint, and directly inspecting the stack frame without running the program, `radare2` shows a different stack frame :

```
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF  comment
0xffa63d10  0100 0000 1953 a6ff 0000 0000 2953 a6ff  .....S......)S..  ; esp
                ^         ^         ^       
              argc     argv[0]    argv[1]
```

When inspecting `argv[0]` :

```
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF  comment
0xffa65319  2e2f 6172 6776 6f6e 7374 6163 6b33 3200  ./argvonstack32.
0xffa65329  5348 454c 4c3d 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 6800  SHELL=/bin/bash.
```

That shows that `radare2` skipped the first pointer indirection of `argv` and pushed the list `argv[0]...argv[argc]` directly onto the `main` stack frame.

What explains such a difference ?

***PS:*** As you can see, the only difference there is between my usage of `radare2` and `gdb` was that I runned the program in `gdb` while  didn't need to actually run it on `radare2` to dump the `main` stack frame memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sort of comparing oranges and apples.

In the first example, you are looking at the arguments passed to the `main` function by the C library, and they match the C standard requirements (array of `char` pointers).

In the second example, you are looking at the low level *entry point* to the binary and the parameters *from the kernel*, before they have been processed by the C library. The kernel does no fancy processing: it just puts all strings in one block delimited by zero bytes (and terminated with two zeroes) and leaves the splitting to the program itself. Usually this is done by `__libc_start_main` or similar function before calling `main()`.