# x86 main preamble makes stack aligned on 32-bytes boundaries

Tags: disassembly, x86, memory, stack

For the record, I've read all stackexchange relevant answers on the topic ([here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14880/basic-reversing-question-about-local-variable) and [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15173/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-instructions-before-the-main-preamble)) plus other articles to fully grasp the concepts of *memory alignment* and *CPU natural boundaries*.
But for some reason, I just can't understand the meaning of the following main preamble (given out by `radare2`)

```
(fcn) sym.main 99
|   sym.main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
|           ; var int local_78h @ ebp-0x78
|           ; arg int arg_10h @ ebp+0x10
|           ; var int local_4h @ esp+0x4
|           ; DATA XREF from entry0 (0x8048417)
|           0x0804867d      55             push ebp
|           0x0804867e      89e5           mov ebp, esp
|           0x08048680      81ec88000000   sub esp, 0x88
|           0x08048686      83e4f0         and esp, 0xfffffff0
|           0x08048689      b800000000     mov eax, 0
|           0x0804868e      83c00f         add eax, 0xf
|           0x08048691      83c00f         add eax, 0xf
|           0x08048694      c1e804         shr eax, 4
|           0x08048697      c1e004         shl eax, 4
|           0x0804869a      29c4           sub esp, eax
```

---

### Breakdown

There seems to be a local array on the stack frame that takes up  *78h = 120d* bytes on the stack, indicated by this line :

```
|           ; var int local_78h @ ebp-0x78
```

So far so good.
Now the stack pointer is moved to make space for such an array on the stack, manipulating `esp` to make sure the stack is aligned on *16-bytes boundaries* :

```
|           0x08048680      81ec88000000   sub esp, 0x88
|           0x08048686      83e4f0         and esp, 0xfffffff0
```

Which effectively makes `esp` a multiple of at least *16* (**least significant nibble** zeroed out), but let's for the sake of mathematical rigor say that `esp` is now a multiple of *16k*, with *k* an arbitrary integer.
All this makes perfect sense (see [here](http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703211/why-128bit-variables-should-be-aligned-to-16byte-boundary) to fully understand the need for *16-bytes stack alignment*, having to do with *SSE* and whatnot).
Now what I really can't seem to wrap my head around is the relevance of the subsequent instructions :

```
|           0x08048689      b800000000     mov eax, 0
|           0x0804868e      83c00f         add eax, 0xf
|           0x08048691      83c00f         add eax, 0xf
|           0x08048694      c1e804         shr eax, 4
|           0x08048697      c1e004         shl eax, 4
|           0x0804869a      29c4           sub esp, eax
```

Which as far as I could understand :
1 - Made `eax` equal to *10h* (by the way why all these instructions to get to such a simple result for `eax` ? Why not just make a `mov eax, 0x10` ?)
2 - Subtract that quantity from `esp`, which is just gonna zero out the **least significant 1 bit** in `esp` (given that the *first nibble* is null anyway) which is just gonna make `esp` a multiple of *16(k+**1**)*, thus making the stack aligned on ***32***-bytes boundaries if it was aligned on ***16***-bytes boundaries, or make it aligned on ***64***-bytes boundaries if it was aligned on ***32***-bytes boundaries, and so on and so forth.

What do we need that for ?
Is there something I got wrong in this whole analysis ?

Answer (score 2):

> There seems to be a local array on the stack frame that takes up 78h =
>   120d bytes on the stack, indicated by this line :

no the local var is of type int and it takes 4 bytes on 32 bit machine
it is located at the address ebp - 0x78
the other one is again a int and is located at esp+4

the circus is probably some home grown obfuscation may be

all it does is subtract another 0x10 from esp

so basically it is sub esp 0x98

you can check whats going on by emulating it or single stepping through it

simple check using python

```
>>> eax = 0
>>> eax
0
>>> eax = eax+0xf
>>> eax
15
>>> eax = eax + 0xf
>>> eax
30
>>> eax = eax >> 4
>>> eax
1
>>> eax = eax << 4
>>> eax
16
>>> hex(eax)
'0x10'
>>>
```

subtracting is not for alignment as you seem to be confusing it
subtracting is making space in stack

the alignment is done with and esp,0x.....

Comment: Fair enough. But then why bother to allocate 98h = 152d  bytes on the stack for two miserable 4-byte integers ?

Comment: cannot infer the reason from the posted snippet may be it is doing some stuff and radare2 didn't find enough evidence to name them as local to the function